# Get Webhook/Alert from YT api when my video is trending

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, google-trends

I'm looking for a way to be aware when one video in my YouTube channel is trending, even from last year.
I saw YouTube has 3 types of webhooks for when a video is uploaded, the title is updated and the description is the updated.

From the doc there is the /trending api, which returns the top trending video for a specific country (regionCode) and video category. Couldn't find anything interesting neither in Channel section.

Do you know any method that I'm missing? Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by: `even from last year`? = as far as I know, the trending videos changes and no record of previous trending videos exists...

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd like to know if there is a way to be notified/retrieve video in my channel which are trending. Like, maybe today I post a video on my channel and somehow it will go trending on January. When it happens, I'd like to know it and retrieve its insights. Is it clearer now? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

However, you can:

- Research about how YouTube says when a video is trending.
- Using the YouTube Data API, check the ["trending now" playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-) everyday and loop the videos on that said playlist, then, check if one of the trending videos are from your channel.

[Sample call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-%22%7D) to the `playlistitems:list` endpoint for obtain the items on the "trending now" playlist.